# Combining %like% and %in% operators in R

Tags: r, data.table

How I can combine %like% with %in% operator in data.table? I would like to find string pattern in any string in list, like:

```
list = c("aaa", "bbb", "ccc")

data[column1 %like% %in% list, column2]
```

which is of course not working.

Comment: Whey do you need both.  I guess you need `data[column1 %in% list]`  (note the `,` in `data.table`)

Comment: @akrun Yes, I meant filtering in i part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the `grep` based approach should work

```
data[grepl(paste(list, collapse='|'), column1)]
```

and if they are exact matches, just do

```
data[column1 %in% list]
```

Comment: How it could ignore letter size?

Comment: @Kulis DId you meant lower/upper case? `grep` also have an argument `ignore.case` which by default is `FALSE`, you can do `data[grepl(paste(list, collapse='|', ignore.case = TRUE), column1)]`

Comment: Yes, lower/upper case,